# defaults for version 8.0.1766 go away once I define ~/.vimrc

Tags: vimrc

Evidently Ubuntu 18.10 is using a new version of vim ( 8.0.1766 ) which gives cool defaults I really like ( immediately jump to search matches while I type in more characters when doing a :/mysearchhere ) however once I create a new file

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

and give it

```
set ts=4
```

that new vim behavior goes away - how to keep new defaults yet define the tab size ?   I use no custom vim settings at all on a fresh Ubuntu 18.10 install

```
apt-cache policy vim
vim:
  Installed: 2:8.0.1766-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:8.0.1766-1ubuntu1
```

after I delete ~/.vimrc  those new default behaviors return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Vim now has some `defaults.vim` located at `$VIMRUNTIME`. It is loaded only if user doesn't have `~/.vimrc` file. If you wan't to keep those defaults you can probably add something like this to the beggining of your `~/.vimrc`

```
if filereadable("$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim")
    source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
endif
```